# Ways to color 6 squares from a 5 x 3 board considering restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, coloring

> Consider a board with 15 squares in 5 rows and 3 columns. In how many ways can 6 squares from this board be painted in a single color, in such a way that exactly 2 painted squares are in each column and at least one painted square is found in each row.

**My proposed solution**: (a) Notice that exactly one row will have 2 painted squares. There are 5 ways to choose the row with 2 squares, and 3 ways to select the places for the 2 squares in this row [suppose I selected row 1 and squares at position (row=1,column=1) and (1,3)]; (b) then I selected the other colored square for column 1, and there are 4 possible ways, on rows 2,3,4,5 [for instance, suppose I selected square (4,1)].
(c) then I selected the other colored square in column 3, and there are 3 possibilities as row 1 is already taken and also not possible on row 4 (as there is just one line with 2 squares); (d) now I will place the 2 colored squares left on column 2. There is just 1 way to do that, at rows 2 and 3.

Therefore there are $5\times 3\times 4\times 3=180$ ways to color 6 squares from this board with the restrictions imposed.

**Questions:** (1) is this solution correct? (2) can you provide a better way to approach problems like this?

Comment: Your method is absolutely fine.